# Shapefile to GeoServer publishing to store error

Tags: python, geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I am trying to publish a shapefile (archived) to GeoServer, by using a Python script, then display the shapefile via WMS in JOSM.
When I publish it to a new Workspace it works fine, it is displayed in JOSM. When I publish it to an existing Store within the workspace or when I create a new store within the workspace, I cannot retrieve it via WMS in JOSM. It is only displaying the first shapefile sent to that workspace.

Code is below:

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog
from geoserver.util import shapefile_and_friends

geoserver_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/'
from geoserver.workspace import ResourceInfo
cat = Catalog(geoserver_uri + 'rest')
# topp = cat.get_workspace("topp")
# shapefile_plus_sidecars = shapefile_and_friends("Tasmania roads")
# print(shapefile_plus_sidecars)
wks_name = 'newWorkspace'
uri = geoserver_uri + wks_name
store_name = 'cityName'
data = r"C:\Users\this_pc\Documents\cities\cityName.zip"


def check_workspace(workspace_name):
    check_workspace = False #create a variable to test if workspace exists already
    if(cat.get_workspaces(workspace_name)):
        check_workspace = True #set the variable to true, if workspace exists
    return check_workspace

#check_workspace(wks_name)
#check_store = False

def create_data(store_name, data, data_name, wks_name):
    cat.create_featurestore(store_name, data, workspace=wks_name)
    cat.add_data_to_store(store=store_name, name=data_name, data=data, workspace=wks_name)

if check_workspace(wks_name): # if workspace exists, create the featurestore
    print("Workspace exists")
    if(cat.get_store(store_name, workspace=wks_name)):
        cat.add_data_to_store(store=store_name, name=store_name, data=data, workspace=wks_name)
        print("Store found. Data has been written.")
    else:
        print("Store does not exist. Store has been created. Data has been written to the store.")
        create_data(store_name, data, "Test name", wks_name)

else: #if workspace does not exists, create the workspace and the featurestore
    cat.create_workspace(wks_name, uri)
    create_data(store_name, data, "Test name", wks_name)
    print("Workspace does not exist. Workspace and store has been created. Data has been written to the store.")
```

Edit: Also, when I publish it, the zip file is erased from local drive.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/paul.nicoara/Documents/Slack/Mapillary_DB/save_geoserver.py", line 40, in 
>       create_data(store_name, data, "Test name", wks_name)
>     File "C:/Users/paul.nicoara/Documents/Slack/Mapillary_DB/save_geoserver.py", line 27, in create_data
>       cat.add_data_to_store(store=store_name, name=data_name, data=data, workspace=wks_name)
>     File "C:\Users\paul.nicoara\PycharmProjects\Mapillary_DB\venv\lib\site-packages\geoserver\catalog.py", line 429, in add_data_to_store
>       with open(bundle, "rb") as f:
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\this_pc\Documents\cities\Bandung.zip'

Comment: Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: this is the current error. It says the zip file does not exist. I have checked the folder and somehow it gets deleted when i run the script.